# Trying to uninstall a keyboard, 'uninstall' grayed out, no root

Tags: keyboard, uninstallation

I'm trying to uninstall PDAC Multilinugal keyboard and its language packs. The uninstall button on the app is grayed out, and I don't yet have root - is it possible to remove it without root access?

Comment: What phone do you have?  Did it come pre-installed?

Comment: Looks like the PDAC multilingual keyboard comes pre-installed on a lot of HTC devices.

Comment: @Matthew - HTC Desire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most pre-installed keyboards are system apps.  System apps can't be uninstalled without root access.

Comment: Damn. The thing is I wouldn't have minded it staying, the problem is it keeps overriding Swype as the default keyboard. Looks like I have to root it then.