# How to uninstall Quickoffice from HTC Nexus One

Tags: nexus-one, uninstallation

Quickoffice 2.0-GEP is listed in my manage application lists and I want to uninstall it. It's not listed in my programs list. I am not even sure what it's used for.

When I click on it from the manage apps list all the options (force stop, cancel, clear data etc.) are greyed out.

Comment: Are you rooted?

Comment: @matthew note rooted

Comment: Closely related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-to-remove-pre-installed-apps-like-peep-and-friend-stream-from-my-htc-phone http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/408/how-can-you-uninstall-an-app-that-you-didnt-install-on-your-droid http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9417/trying-to-uninstall-a-keyboard-uninstall-grayed-out-no-root

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove any system default applications your phone must be rooted. And using this [system app remover](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.danesh.system.app.remover) you can remove the system added applications. But you have to do this on your own risk.

I have been doing a lot of research on Android mobiles, I can tell that your system **might** not work properly if you remove any system added applications.
But most of the applications work fine without any issue.

**Updated**

[System App Remover](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.danesh.system.app.remover) is a paid application. There is one free application called [Root App Delete](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=zsj.android.uninstall). Have a look at this..

Answer (score 3):

Quickoffice is a pre-installed app that handles previews of popular file formats created with desktop office applications (e.g. word, excel, etc.)  You will not be able to uninstall it because it's installed as a system app.

You will only be able to uninstall it if you root your Nexus One, thus gaining write privileges to the /system partition.  You can then use a number of root-only apps to remove Quickoffice and other pre-installed apps that you don't use.